# Xamarin Progress dialog to show and hide

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am having some difficulty in showing the progress view in my Xamarin app. I believe its do with the different threads. Here is my code.

```
private void NavigateCommand()
    {
       using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Verifying Credentials",null, null, true, MaskType.Black))
                {
                try
                    {
                    var authResult = Task.Run(async () => await _loginService
                                            .Login(Priority.Background, EmailAddress.Value, Password.Value)
                                                  .ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;

                        CacheToken(authResult);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading());
            _navigationService.NavigateAsync("PageOnePage");
    }
```

So what is happening now is that, the progress/loading view does not show until the second last line (which is the code for hiding) is executed. Its a quick flash and it disappears. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work as it places your `UserDialogs`/ `NavigateAsync` calls on the UI thread and `Login`/`CacheToken` on a background thread:

```
private void NavigateCommand()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Verifying Credentials", null, null, true, MaskType.Black))
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await _loginService.Login(Priority.Background, EmailAddress.Value, Password.Value);
                CacheToken(authResult);
            });
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                _navigationService.NavigateAsync("PageOnePage");
            });
        }
    });
}
```